# How to parse log file by regex grouping

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to parse based on the grouping, below is the input file to parse.
Cannot able to aggregate multiple groups from my regex which produces expected output. Need some recommendations to print data in expected output. (Note Group2 can have different other (strings) in the actual log-file)

#Parse out the timedate stamp Jan 20 03:25:08 to capture two groups
Example groups
1.) Jan 20 03:25 2.) logrotate

1.) Jan 20 05:03 2.) ntpd

```
logfile= """Jan 20 03:25:08 fakehost logrotate: ALERT exited abnormally with [1]
Jan 20 03:25:08 fakehost run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[20447]: finished logrotate
Jan 20 03:26:21 fakehost anacron[28969]: Job 'cron.daily' terminated
Jan 20 03:26:21 fakehost anacron[28969]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Jan 20 03:30:01 fakehost CROND[31462]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jan 20 03:30:01 fakehost CROND[31461]: (root) CMD (/var/system/bin/sys-cmd -F
Jan 20 05:03:03 fakehost ntpd[3705]: synchronized to time.faux.biz, stratum 2
"""
```

Expected output:

```
minute,total_count,logrotate,CROND,ntpd,anacron,run-parts
Jan 20 03:25,2,1,0,0,0,1
Jan 20 03:26,2,0,2,0,1,1
Jan 20 03:30,2,0,2,0,0,0
Jan 20 05:03,1,0,0,1,0,0
```

This is my code:

```
import re
output = {} 
regex = re.compile(r'^(\w+ \d+ \d+:\d+):\d+ \w+ (\w+).*$')
with open("logfile", "r+") as myfile:
    for log_line in myfile:
        match = regex.match(log_line)
        if match:
            if match.group(1) and match.group(2):
                print(match.groups())

                # Struck here to arrange the data
                output[match.group(1)]['total_count'] += 1
                output[match.group(1)][match.group(2)] += 1


for k, v in output.items():
    print('{0} {1}'.format(k, v))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and how to provide a [mre]. It's not clear how you get that output from that input, so could you please add an explanation? Also, please [edit] your post to include what went wrong with your code and ask a _specific_ question.

Comment: I'm not able to figure out the expected output because I can't quite tell how it is mapped to the lines of the input string. Can you highlight which parts of your input string's lines you want to extract ?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi updated question with more details

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar updated grouping examples I'm trying to parse and more accurate expected output to the given input

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
output = []
regex = re.compile(r'^(\w+ \d+ \d+:\d+):\d+ \w+ (\w+).*$')


with open("logfile.txt", "r+") as myfile:
    for log_line in myfile:
        match = regex.match(log_line)
        if match:
            if match.group(1) and match.group(2):

            dataDict = {'minute': match.group(1), 'total_count': 1}

            dataDict[match.group(2)] = 1

            lastInsertedIndex = len(output) - 1

            if (len(output) > 0):  # data exist, check if same minute data exist or not

                # same minute, update existing data
                if (output[lastInsertedIndex]['minute'] == match.group(1)):

                    lastInsertedIndexDict = output[lastInsertedIndex]

                    if (match.group(2) in lastInsertedIndexDict):
                        lastInsertedIndexDict[match.group(2)] = lastInsertedIndexDict[match.group(2)] + 1  # updating group(2)
                    else:
                        lastInsertedIndexDict[match.group(2)] = 1
                        
                    # updating total count
                    lastInsertedIndexDict['total_count'] = lastInsertedIndexDict['total_count'] + 1

                    output[lastInsertedIndex] = lastInsertedIndexDict

                else:  # new minute, simply append
                    output.append(dataDict)

            else:  # output list is empty
                output.append(dataDict)

for data in output:
    print(data)
```

Here the idea is after we have `match.groups()`, create a dictionary with `minute` as a key & for `total_count` value as 1. Then for `match.group(1)` set value as 1 with the new found key.

As the data would be in increasing order of time, so check if previously inserted data is of same minute or different minute.
If same minute then increase the dictionary's `total_count` & `match.group(2)` values by 1
If different minute then simply append the dictionary to output list

Currently output list would print keys & values. Incase if you want to print only values then instead of `print(data)` in the last line, you can change to `print(data.values())`

Just to mention, I have assumed that you are not facing any issue in regex & that whatever regex you have provided is fulfilling your requirement.
In case you face any issue in regex or need help in that do let me know in comment.

Comment: thank you!, which helps me to move one step towards the solution. Is there a way not to hard-code group(2) which can be others as well in the actual log file. Regex part is good which captures group 1 & 2 as expected .

Comment: @knowit I have updated the code with your requirement of not hardcoding the keys. Just simply create a dictionary with minute & total_count as keys. Then whatever key is found by group(2), added it to the dictionary with 1 as value. When you get new data & the minute is same, then check if that same key exist, if yes then update its value by 1 else just add the new group(2) with its value set to 1